# How can I redraw my datatable with new parameters?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, datatables, twig

I created a serverside processing datatable

```
   var table = $('.table').DataTable({
         "serverSide": true,
         "ajax": '{{ path('json', { 'fileName': output.fileName }) }}',
 ....
```

This is filled with with 10 datatable entries, but displaying in the footer a total records of 5000

```
{"draw":1,"recordsTotal":5000,"recordsFiltered":5000,"data":[{"id":536,"uuid"....
```

I have now an ajax request and on success I would like to reload the datatable:

```
 $.ajax({
    method:'POST',
    data: {
      "id": id,
      "length": length,
    },
    url:'{{ path('json', { 'fileName': output.fileName }) }}',
    success : function (data) {
      table.destroy();
      var oTable = $('.table').dataTable({  });
      oTable.fnDraw();

    }
  });
```

Now I still see 10 entries, but the totalRecords that are displayed in the footer of the datatable has changed to 10, but it should still be 5000. What can I do?

Comment: Side question: Are you able to update DataTables to the latest version? I think `fnDraw()` is from a very (very!) old release. Otherwise, what version are you using?

Comment: hm good questions, I just found fnDraw on the website tutorials, I am not sure what version I have, it comes with Bootstrap datatables for Bootstrap 3

Comment: You know I actually just would like to reload my datatable with some new parameters

Comment: Do you think in this case I should use `table.ajax.reload();`?

Comment: A simple `table.draw()` will reload the table (i.e. do a clean fetch of your server-side data). But you need to use the same reference to the original initialized table `var table = $('.table').DataTable({...`. At least that is how I have used it - there may be other ways.  This is for DataTables 1.10. It could be different for your older version (which may be 1.9, I think). If you really want to reload the table "with some new [i.e. different] parameters", then you need the `dataFilter` option for jQuery's `ajax` call. But I don't know under what circumstances that would make sense for you.

Comment: One final comment.  This looks suspicious (should have noticed it earlier): `var oTable = $('.table').dataTable({  });` This re-initializes the table (which I would expect to throw an error, actually). Instead, do this: `var oTable = $('.table').dataTable();`.